# ASP.NET Core MVC: Why is the optional list parameter never null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC Application and I've got an Index method in my Controller. When the Index method is called for the first time, I want the parameter that holds the resultList of a search to be null. This is because I want to handle an empty resultList differently than a non existing one.

So I tried the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(List<SomeModel> resultList = null)
```

But whenever I start the Web App the list is empty not null. Why is this? And do I have a chance to get a list that is null?

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to get a `resultList` to null is to create another list.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(List<SomeModel> resultList) 
    {
        if (resultList != null)
        {
          //...
        }
        //there the result will be null,you can do your logic with this result. 
        List<UserAddress> result = null;
        //...
    }
```

Comment: The problem is, that the resultList is never null. But it can be the case the resultList ist really empty. In the case of an empty list, I need to handle it differentlich than null. For now I solved my problem with an additional boolean that helps me indicate wether the list is actually null and not empty. But I'd really love to know why the list ist never null in my Conntroller action method.

Comment: My personal understanding is that the built-in method in the model binding checks that the list is set to null, and no space is allocated for it, causing it to initialize instead of setting the default value.